# Meaning of "took the bend"

Tags: meaning

I come across the the sentence below in Longman Dictionary of Contemporary Dictionary.(http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/take-a-bend-fence-corner-etc)

> He took the bend at over 60 and lost control.

I can not figure out exactly what this sentence means. 
I have a guess, though.
It seems like 'He' was driving now and lost control of his car, trying to go around the corner over 60 MPH.
Am I right?

Comment: "Bend in the road" is an idiomatic way to describe a curve.

Comment: "Curve" is a word that Americans use to refer to a bend in the road. "Bend" is the normal word in the UK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are absolutely right. It means he turned the car at a speed of over 60 mph  and lost control. The speed of the car, not the curvature of the turn, is suggested. It is pertinent to mark the use of the preposition 'AT'. The sense would be crystal clear.